# Appropriate use of `void **` for garbage-collected structs in C?

Tags: c, garbage-collection, void-pointers, c11, suppress-warnings

I need some help with `void **` pointers.

In implementing a garbage collector in C (automatic reference counting), I've found I need a special assignment operator (similar to what C++ does with std::shared_ptr when assigning to one when it already holds a pointer). In its larger context, it fits into a small implementation of the DOM and so far I've gotten away with using generic `void *` pointers to hold strong/weak references.

The problem I am currently facing is how to abstract away re-assignment of a strong/weak reference, e.g.:

```c
#define DOMStrongRef(T) T*

DOMStrongRef(struct dom_node) node = dom_strong_add_ref(existing_node_ref);
DOMStrongRef(struct dom_node) tmp = dom_strong_add_ref(node->parent);
dom_strong_release(node);
node = tmp;
```

This is both ugly and error-prone, as even this simplified example, it is not directly clear which pointer is the "live" one, which has already caused me dumb reference counting errors before.

I am looking for a simple, short way to write this, something like.

```c
DOMStrongRef(struct dom_node) node = dom_strong_add_ref(existing_node_ref);
dom_strong_assign(&node, other_node) // release old ref, assign new
```

Also, to clarify, here's what the GC looks like:

```c
typedef struct DOMHeader_s {
  struct vtable * vtable;
  int_least32_t strong_refcnt;
  int_least32_t weak_refcnt;
} DOMHeader;

typedef void DOMAny;

static inline DOMStrongRef(DOMAny)
dom_strong_add_ref(DOMAny *any)
{
  if (any != NULL)
    ((DOMHeader *) any)->header.strong_refcnt++;

  return any;
}

static inline void
dom_strong_release(DOMStrongRef(DOMAny) any)
{
  DOMHeader *hdr = any;

  if (hdr != NULL && --obj->header.strong_refcnt <= 0)
    dom__destroy(obj); /* call dtors, free() *
}

/* idem for weak refs, except no dom__destroy */

/*
```

PS: Thread safety is not required, but it would be nice if someone could also briefly hint at how it would be done in that case, as references also reside within structs, like `struct dom_node`'s `parent`, for example.

Here's the relevant code I have tried:

```c
/* dom/dom.h */

typedef void DOMAny;

#define DOMStrongRef(T) T* 
#define DOMWeakRef(T) T*

static inline void
dom_strong_assign(DOMStrongRef(DOMAny) *dest, DOMAny *src)
{
  if (*dest != NULL)
    dom_strong_release(*dest);

 *dest = dom_strong_add_ref(src);
}
```

Where `dom_strong_add_ref` and `dom_strong_release` handle `int32_t` reference counts of `*src`, potentially deallocating the struct during the latter.

However, when using this function, I get warnings of the following kind:

```
gcc -c -o build/dom/core/node.o -MMD -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -O2 -ggdb3 -I. dom/core/node.c
In file included from dom/core/node.c:1:
./dom/core/node.h: In function ‘dom_get_object_root’:
./dom/core/node.h:50:23: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘dom_strong_assign’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   50 |     dom_strong_assign(&a, a->parent);
      |                       ^~
      |                       |
      |                       struct dom_node **
```

I have looked up this specific implicit conversion online with no success, and I wouldn't consider putting a forced `(DOMAny **)` cast a solution. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why aren't you using a typedef struct pointer, implemented as opaque type? Those macros are pure evil. Although with C23 `typeof`, you may be able to create something similar to templates through more intricate, safer macros...

Comment: But all in all this kind of seems like a solution looking for a problem that it solves. What's the chances of introducing bugs in a program using an awkward template smart pointer language, compared to just manually handling allocation? Memory leaks are after all the easier kind of bugs to spot nowadays. Peculiar void pointer bugs achieved through some macro language... far harder. For those in need of a collection of garbage, there's always Github :)

Comment: Been having the same problem and haven't found any better solution than explicitly casting to `void**`, other than creating wrapper functions that take in the correct type and forward it. The second solution is the best but requires some boiler code (which can be easily reduced with macros).

Comment: In C, there are implicit conversions from `void *` to and from all other object-pointer types, but make no mistake: these are *conversions*.  `void *` is *bona fide*, complete type, distinct from all other types.  In any given C implementation, it has a specific size and representation.  It follows that `void **` cannot have analogous implicit conversion behavior.  A pointer to `void *` points *only* to `void *`, because other pointer types are permitted to have different representation.

Comment: Using a more specific pointer type than `void *` would probably help some.  Maybe that type would be `DOMHeader *`.  I anticipate that you will still need explicit conversions in some places, however.

Comment: @Lundin I get your point, but in my program the structs are never free()'d in the same scope as they are allocated, so I don't really see a way around garbage collection, so it would be nice if you could elaborate on what you mean by using opaque typedef struct pointers.

Comment: @rshadr Examples here: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888) Basically a forward declaration in a header, but a struct definition in the .c file, achieving private encapsulation. As for how to integrate that with `typeof` in a sensible manner, well that's another story...

Comment: Don't edit your question with the answer. Post the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

C23 macro which does exactly this (thanks to comments):

```c
#define dom_strong_assign(dest, src) \
  dom_strong_assign_((dest), (src), typeof((dest)), typeof((src)))

/* assert() can be evaluated at compile time */
#define dom_strong_assign_(dest, src, tdest, tsrc) \
  do { \
    assert(!strcmp(#tdest, #tsrc)); \
    if (*dest != NULL) \
      dom_strong_release(*dest); \
    *dest = dom_strong_add_ref(src); \
  } while (0)
```